# PWM Control using Verilog problem

Tags: fpga, pwm, verilog, control

My PWM control is having issue,I don't know why...

So I'll briefly describe my PWM specs;

a 4-bit Input named `value`,

Input clock 50MHz,

a single bit output `PWM_out`,

Duty cycle is equal to 1/16 of input clock and

it changes when the `value` input is changed.

like, Value = 0000, Duty Cycle=0%

Value = 0001,Duty Cycle=6.25%

Value = 0010,Duty Cycle=12.5%

Value = 0010,Duty Cycle=18.75%

.... etc

when value changed,duty cycle should be increased by 6.25%

Here is my code and output doesn't seem correct;

```
module pwm_c(clk,value,PWM_out,counter);
input clk;
input [3:0] value;
output PWM_out;
reg PWM_out;

output reg [3:0]counter;

//parameter rst=1;

always@(posedge clk)
    begin
        if(!rst)
            counter <= 4'd0;
        else
            counter <= counter + 4'd1;
    end

always@(counter or value)
    begin
        if(value == 4'd0)
            PWM_out = 1'b0;
        else if(value == 4'd1)
            PWM_out = (counter >=4'd1) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd2)
            PWM_out = (counter >=4'd2) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd3)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd3) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd4)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd4) ? 1'b0:1'b1;

        else if(value == 4'd5)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd5) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd6)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd6) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd7)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd7) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd8)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd8) ? 1'b0:1'b1;


        else if(value == 4'd9)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd9) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd10)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd10) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd11)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd11) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd12)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd12) ? 1'b0:1'b1;

        else if(value == 4'd13)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd13) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd14)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd14) ? 1'b0:1'b1;
        else if(value == 4'd15)
            PWM_out = (counter >= 4'd15) ? 1'b0:1'b1;


        else
            PWM_out = 1'b0;
    end

endmodule
```

Although I've asked a friend who knew a little more about Verilog than me,
He said,
I have to divide the input `value` by 16,per `value` is equal to 16 clocks of input clock.
I don't quite understand how to implement this...
I don't understand how to divide `value` input,'cause in my thoughts that's 4 manual switches or wires..
How do you divide something that's controlled manually?

Please anyone help me...Thanks...

edit;
adding all and each suggestions,still not the result I expect.the third picture is by far I tried to get as close as I wanted,but if you look at the `value`,It still doesn't divided by 16 and `PWM_out` starts to have output from `value=3` not `value=1`...

edit2;
So I asked my friend once more,and it suggested that `value` has to 16 times of `clk`,which means I have to make `value` changes after full 16 pulses of `clk`,but I just haven't have the faintest idea to implement this.

maybe I wasn't cleared enough...down below is what I transit in my brain of above's suggestion..

`value` has to be **full 16 cycles of clk** before change,and then `PWM_out` to output...like,`value=0,PWM_out=0` and `value` changes after **16 pulses of clk**, `value=1,PWM_out=1`,`value` changes after **16 pulses of clk**...so on and so on... **each time it change** the `PWM_out` is **wider and wider** like, `value =0,PWM_out=0`, changes after **16 pulses of clk**,`value=1,PWM_out=1(equal to almost one pulse of clk)` , `value=2,PWM_out=2(equal to one pulse of clk)`...so on.

the `PWM_out` should be close to the third picture,but should be from tighter to wider and the `value` has to match the **full 16 cycles of `clk`**.

edit3:
Okay,so I think maybe I take the third picture's wave result to draw out what I described in edit2...maybe the drawn picture would much better to help to think...drawn picture in Fifth Picture.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image: my final goal,what I expected,watch the one that marked with red rectangular.]

Comment: The very same question was posted before and then removed by the author. Now it is posted with the very same text without even a sign of any adaption or effort to follow the suggestions. IMHO the author should try to understand what was written to the first post. E.g. the reset is still static so nothing will happen. Or to put it in a more offensive way: try to show at least some effort and either try to understand and answer the comments carefully or learn to properly debug your stuff yourself (i.e. use a simulation program) .

Comment: @ChristianB. I did tried every suggestion,did you want me to post each time I modified code? I could,I'm not waiting the answer,I don't expect,I want to post each update,but the posting characters has limited.
While I'm asking,I'm also trying...

Comment: @ChristianB.You asked,I updated.Now,would you provide me more thoughts to adjust,fix this,I'm in serious logically stuck...

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. Especially the waveforms are helping to see that the issue is. Question: why is **value** changing so fast? normally it should be fixed for at least a full cycle (i.e.16 clk pulses) and only change for every new cycle. If it cannot be guaranteed that **value** will not change within one complete cycle one can make a locale copy very time counter is zero to make your module robust against "sudden" changes of **value**.

Comment: @ChristianB. Your question is exactly what I wondered too,I want `value` to be full 16 cycles of clk before change,and then `PWM_out` to output...like,`value=0` , `PWM_out=0` and `value` change after 16 pulses of clk, then `value=1`,`PWM_out=1` `value change after 16 pulses of clk...so on and so on...
each time it change the `PWM_out` is wider and wider like,  `value =0`,`PWM_out=0`, changes after 16 pulses of clk,`value=1`,`PWM_out=1(equal to almost one pulse of clk)`  , `value=2`,`PWM_out=2(equal to one pulse of clk)`...so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling the information you added later the following should work:

```
module pwm_d
(
    input   wire    rst,
    input   wire    clk,
    input   wire    [3:0] cmp_value,
    output  wire    PWM_out,
    //for debugging
    output  reg     [3:0] clk_counter
);

reg [3:0] stored_cmp_value;

assign PWM_out = clk_counter < stored_cmp_value;

always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if(rst) begin
        clk_counter         <= 4'd0;
        stored_cmp_value    <= 4'd0;
    end else begin
        clk_counter         <= clk_counter + 4'd1;
        stored_cmp_value    <= clk_counter != 4'd15 ? stored_cmp_value : cmp_value;
    end
end

endmodule
```

and the testbench:

```
module simulation();

    reg clk_x1;
    reg rst;  
    reg [7:0] counter_A;


pwm_d UUT(
        .clk(clk_x1),         
        .rst(rst),
        .cmp_value(counter_A[7:4])
    );


initial begin                                         
    rst = 0;  
    clk_x1 = 0;
    counter_A = 0;
    #50 rst = 1;
    #200 rst = 0;
end

always begin
    #1 clk_x1 = ~clk_x1;
    counter_A = counter_A + clk_x1;
end

endmodule
```

This way the comparsion value will only change for every new cycle. Basically the only real issue with the already tried/suggested solutions is that the compare value is changing "to fast"/ at the wrong time.

EDIT: corrected source. The module does not work for a 100% PWM (so always on) case. 
EDIT2: added testbench.

[image: waveform of simulateion]

Comment: I'm sorry,it's still not close enough...the [wave result](https://i.imgur.com/U5ZK0IU.png),this way,the `value` is still changing too fast...
I still have't have the faintest idea to slow down the 4-bit input `value`...

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for the not correct source. I wrote it out of my head and inserted many misstakes. Updated the source and added the simulation result for comparison.

Comment: I don't know why,but your simulation looks perfect,I used your module to simulated,and it came out two kinds of results,both are not like yours,first one `rst=0` [first result](https://imgur.com/CwrYOVi.png),second one,[second result](https://imgur.com/AwsbD6E.png).

Comment: I have just updated in the main post with a fifth picture,maybe it'll be much more clear of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: the main difference is that your ```value``` changes to quickly. So you have to correct the way to generate/increment it. I actually used a 8bit wide counter (```reg [7:0] counter```) and which is increased by 1 for every clk pulse and ```value``` is set to ```counter[7:4]```

Comment: Wait what?How do you set input `value` to `counter[7:4]`?Did you just simply add `assign value = counter[7:4];`? I thought about using a 8-bit counter but then again I don't see any `else if` to make it stop at 15 and then count from 0 again.

Comment: wait a minute...`assign value = counter[7:4]` isn't correct. What's the logic of this,to set a `input [3:0] value` to `counter[7:4]`? Can you show me where to set it in your module,besides the `reg [7:0] counter`....

Comment: Well I meant a second counter in the test bench module. I can add the source of it tomorrow.

Comment: @doverdxJYGtw added the sim module as well.

Comment: I tried to add the sim module,but it seems you edited the main module and forgot to edit the test bench as well,It keep saying missing connection for port `PWM_out` and `clk_counter` and `camp_value`.Where do I add them in the test bench?

Comment: There is no camp_value and PWM_out and clk_counter are outputs. If you cannot get it running from this point on by yourself I cannot help you any further...

Comment: I'm sorry,my mistakes.I got it work,but the [wave result](https://imgur.com/cw8DW9V.png) the first four `PWM_out` looks normal,but after it,the fifth still looks weird..thank you anyway.
edit,I used Model-Sim-altera to simulate it,No matter how many times I sim it,it just doesn't look like yours result that much perfect...sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check each possible value of the counter. Instead you could just check it against the value input.

```
module pwm_c(clk,value,PWM_out,counter);
  input clk;
  input [3:0] value;
  output PWM_out;

  output reg [3:0]counter;

  parameter rst=1;

  always@(posedge clk)
      begin
          if(!rst)
              counter <= 4'd0;
          else
              counter <= counter + 4'd1;
      end

  assign PWM_out = (counter > value) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

endmodule
```

Comment: First of all,thank your for your suggestion.
I've thought about this as well,but this doesn't make it variable and isn't controlled by `value`,my goal is when `value = 0` , `PWM_out = 0` ,and `counter` count 1 round from 0~15, `value = 1`,`PWM_out = half cycle of input clock` , `counter` count 1 round from 0~15, `value = 2`,`PWM_out = one cycle of input clock` , `counter` count 1 round from 0~15...etc...
So that's why I tried to compare each value of `counter` and input `value`,but sadly didn't work.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it is flexible controllable by value this way. Actually one can simplify the assign with ```assign PWM_out = counter > value;``` but with ```rst``` being a parameter set to 1 I do not know how this code should ever leave the reset state. But all of those remarks were posted before already...